# How to count empty value and print out that observation?

Tags: r, count

I have a data frame like this:

[image]

The problem is: Print out the name of the object that have the most empty value. As we can see, **c** has 3 empty value so the answer to that problem is **c**

I have used

```
count()
```

and

```
table()
```

but it's obviously wrong. Is there any way in R that I can solve that problem?
I'm sorry, but I don't have enough reputation to post image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking for something like this:

```
test <- cbind.data.frame( # dummy df after picture 
  name = letters[1:5], 
  color = c("B", "R", "" , "W", "R"), 
  shape = c("R", "" , "O", "R", "R"),
  price = c(10 , "" , 30 , 40 , 50),
  weight =c(1  , "" , "" , 3  , 4))

which.max(rowSums(test=="")) # the idea is to count empty spaces ("") per row

[1] 2

#####

test[which.max(rowSums(test=="")),]

  name color shape price weight
2    b     R
```

The test condition is set to `==""` (empty string) and so the whole `data frame` is converted to string. If your missing values are stored with a different character/NA then switch the `""`with the correct missing value/NA.

In the future, please add data via `dput()` instead of images.

Comment: When I try like you, it becomes like this :   [1] NA 
And all of the columns are char type

Comment: Instead of using rowSums(test=="") use rowSums(is.na(test)). Instead of counting blank strings ("") you'll be counting NA values.

Comment: But when i apply the code, it seems like it prints out the row that has the position of the max(rowSums(test==""))   , not the row with the most blank values.

Comment: @Cothd i updated the answer, i forgot to add the `which.max` and only wrote `max()` which as you point out, only shows the max value not its position.

@Athe i agree 100%, if there are `NA` values the whole operation would be cleaner. it is not clear to me though (since the data was provided as image only), that the missing values are encoded as `NA`.